# Making a simple terminal in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a simple console terminal using stdin and stdout. Basically I have a function that inputs something and retrieves something to the chat.

As you know it would say something like `root@192.168.2.1:/` and then I can type ONLY in that line. When I press enter/submit it would appear another line with `root@192.168.2.1:/` for me to type again.

How do I make this to be able to type only in the last line and in front of the `root@192.168.2.1:/` (basically this is locked)?

**Any better ideas to implement this instead of textarea??**

```js
$('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
  var terminal = $('#terminal');
  var stdin = terminal.val();
  console.log(stdin);
  //Get stdout (FAKE FOR THE EXAMPLE)    
  terminal.append(stdout() + '<br>');
});


function stdout(stdin) {
  return "root@192.168.2.1:/"
}
```

```css
.terminal {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<textarea class="terminal" rows="20" id="terminal"></textarea>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit" type="button">Send</button>
```

Comment: I believe it's not possible to insert any HTML into a `textarea` element without it returning the tags as inline strings.

Comment: damn. can someone help me here ? :/

Comment: If a textarea isn't absolutely necessary, you could instead try to use a `div` that has the `contenteditable` attribute? And then add your desired elements there.

Comment: I dont need text area. I was just trying on my own

Answer (score 10):

Like you say, you really only need one line to write in. You could just make that single line an input field and output the "history" in a div abve your input field.

Here is an example, only thing that is not looking like a terminal is the way this scrolls, but I guess that should be fixable with some extra code.

```js
$(function() {
    $('.terminal').on('click', function() {
        $('#input').focus();
    });

    $('#input').on('keydown', function search(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            // append your output to the history,
            // here I just append the input
            $('#history').append($(this).val() + '<br/>');

            // you can change the path if you want
            // crappy implementation here, but you get the idea
            if ($(this).val().substring(0, 3) === 'cd ') {
                $('#path').html($(this).val().substring(3) + '&nbsp;>&nbsp;');
            }

            // clear the input
            $('#input').val('');

        }
    });
});
```

```css
.terminal{
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font: courier;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.line{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.terminal span{
  display:table-cell; 
  width:1px;
}

.terminal input{
  display:table-cell; 
  width:100%;
  border: none;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="terminal">
  <div id="history">
    
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <span id="path">c:/&nbsp;>&nbsp;</span>
    <input type="text" id="input">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to insert an editable div instead.

[JSFiddle Terminal Example](https://jsfiddle.net/5gxrpdjb/)

What I did was to create a pure CSS solution. I created a `flex` wrapper, with a static and editable `div` side by side. This will make sure that whatever digital output is displayed won't interfere with the user input.

**HTML:**

```
<section>
    <div class="static">IP ADDRESS</div>
    <div class="input" contenteditable="true"></div>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
section {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    font-family: monospace;
}
.static {
    width: auto;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.input {
    flex: 1;
}
```